# Classification with different data dimensions

Tags: google-earth-engine, data, algorithm

I am trying to use the continuous change detection classification algorithm (ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc() and it appears to be working for me, however when I get the results the data type is a float and some bands have floats with one dimension while others have float data with two dimensions. I believe that the ccdc can then be used as an input for classification and the classification does not seem to work with data that has different dimensions. What do I need to change?

```
var polygon = /* color: #d6690b */geometry;
var canada = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
                .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','CA'));
var Canada_crop = ee.FeatureCollection("AAFC/ACI")
                      .filterDate('2016-01-01');
//var watershed = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_8")
//                     .filterBounds(polygon)
//                     .map(function(feature){
//    var num = ee.Number.parse(feature.get('areasqkm'));
//    return feature.set('areasqkm', num);
//  });
//var Canadafilter = watershed.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(canada));

//var shed = CA_bounds_all.filterBounds(polygon) ; 
var shed = polygon
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var canlandcover = ee.ImageCollection('AAFC/ACI')
                          .select('landcover')
                          .map(function(image) {return image.clip(shed); });
var land11 = canlandcover
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31'))
    .first()
    .select('landcover');
var names1 = land11.get('landcover_class_names');
///////////////////////////////////////////
var land16 = canlandcover
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31'))
    .first()
    .select('landcover');
var nochange = land16.eq(land11)
var nochange = nochange.updateMask(nochange.eq(1));
var nochange16 = land16.updateMask(nochange)

print(nochange16,'class to use')


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// landsat full collection
// Define the start and finish time
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(1983, 1, 1);
var finish = ee.Date.fromYMD(2020, 1, 1);
// Select Landsat bands respectively as their different band configurations
var l8_bandlist = ee.List(['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10']);
var l7_bandlist = ee.List(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B7', 'B6']);

//Unified the band names in the collection
var rename_list = ee.List(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'tbb']);

//Landsat Collection
var l8_sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(shed).filterDate(
    start, finish).select(l8_bandlist, rename_list).sort('system:time_start').filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 10));

var l7_sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(shed).filterDate(
    start, finish).select(l7_bandlist, rename_list).sort('system:time_start').filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 10));

var l5_sr = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR').filterBounds(shed).filterDate(
    start, finish).select(l7_bandlist, rename_list).sort('system:time_start').filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUD_COVER', 10));
// Rename images again
var old_bandname = rename_list;
var new_bandname = ee.List(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'nir', 'swir1', 'swir2', 'tbb']);
// Function to rename the band names of images in the collection
function  renamelandsatbands(img){
return img.select(
    old_bandname,
    new_bandname
    )}
var l8_dataset = l8_sr.map(renamelandsatbands);
var l7_dataset = l7_sr.map(renamelandsatbands);
var l5_dataset = l5_sr.map(renamelandsatbands);

// Stack landsat series image collection
var lcdataset = l8_dataset.merge(l7_dataset).merge(l5_dataset).sort('system:time_start').filterBounds(shed);
// ccdc
var segmen = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc(lcdataset);
var segmen = segmen.toDouble()
// output of ccdc to be used as input for classification
print(segmen, 'ccdc results')







////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//classification
// train the ccdc with the nochange data
var training02 = segmen.addBands(nochange16)

var training02 = training02.sample({
  region: shed,
  scale: 30,
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  numPixels: 500,
  seed: 0, 
  geometries: true
});
// Make a Random Forest classifier and train it.
var classifier02 = ee.Classifier.randomForest(10)
    .train(training02, 'landcover');

// Classify the input imagery.
var classified02 = segmen.classify(classifier02);
Map.addLayer(classified02, {palette: igbpPalette, min: 0, max: 17}, 'classified')
// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy02 = classifier02.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy02);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy02.accuracy());

// Sample the input with a different random seed to get validation data.
var validation02 = segmen.addBands(nochange16).sample({
  region: shed,
  scale: 30,
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  numPixels: 500,
  seed: 1,
  geometries: true
  // Filter the result to get rid of any null pixels.
}).filter(ee.Filter.neq('B1', null));

// Classify the validation data.
var validated02 = validation02.classify(classifier02);

// Get a confusion matrix representing expected accuracy.
var testAccuracy02 = validated02.errorMatrix('Land_Cover_Type_1', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy02);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy02.accuracy());

// Define a palette
var igbpPalette = [
  'aec3d4', // water
  '152106', '225129', '369b47', '30eb5b', '387242', // forest
  '6a2325', 'c3aa69', 'b76031', 'd9903d', '91af40',  // shrub, grass
  '111149', // wetlands
  'cdb33b', // croplands
  'cc0013', // urban
  '33280d', // crop mosaic
  'd7cdcc', // snow and ice
  'f7e084', // barren
  '6f6f6f'  // tundra
];

// Display the input and the classification.
Map.centerObject(shed, 8);
Map.addLayer(classified02, {palette: igbpPalette, min: 0, max: 17}, 'classification');
```

Comment: This is a very open-ended question. Can you provide some code, and be more specific on what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I have included the code that I am using. I am trying to use the ccdc output as the input for a classification, however I get this error: 
"Property 'tStart' of feature '1': Invalid type. Expected type: Float. Actual type: Float<dimensions=1>. Actual value: [724824.0]"

Answer (score 0):

CCDC output bands are array images, and cannot be used directly for classification.

It's fairly involved working with this output. You might want to check for existing scripts or libraries that already have done this. Here's one that I've made: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/wiell/temporalSegmentation

Some examples on how to use it:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/wiell/temporalSegmentationExamples

I'm not really supporting this code, but you can at least use this to get some ideas on how to implement this yourself. I do seem to recall I've seen another, more recent, (and hopefully more supported), library for simplifying the use of CCDC. I'd appreciate if you post the link here if you do find something.